# What does the yellow and purple highlight mean in notepad++?

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

When I open my PHP file in Notepad++, some statements are highlighted, including the PHP opening and closing tags (which are in purple) and a few statements (in yellow).

What do these highlights mean?

P.S. I know this may seem like a very basic question but I am just new to using notepad++ and coding in general.

Comment: Can you post some of your code that shows this?

Comment: And maybe a screenshot as well.

Comment: Close voters, there is no need to migrate this, it is on topic. There's a link to the [faq] in the close dialog which tells you that questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are fine on SO.

Comment: Voted to close to stop the migration - have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [syntax highlighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting). It just makes it easier to see where functions are, strings are, special code is. From the link:

> Syntax highlighting is a feature of some text editors that display text—especially source code—in different colors and fonts according to the category of terms. This feature eases writing in a structured language such as a programming language or a markup language as both structures and syntax errors are visually distinct. Highlighting does not affect the meaning of the text itself; it is intended only for human readers and editors.

Comment: Presumably he already knows what syntax highlighting is, since it's listed in the question's tags. But it does seem basic enough that he isn't *sure* how exactly it works, so your explanation may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to json style in notepad++, yellow means error.

I don't know if that means there is an error in the json I have in my file, or if there was in an evil error in notepad++ design such that you can't correct your error because the yellow is impossible to read.

[Example of Invalid JSON unreadable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG7te.png)

Comment: Can you share screenshot of what you mean

Comment: Ok.  The Language menu option has JSON selected and here I have a line of valid json followed by a line of invalid json.

Answer (score 0):

-yellow ; tag match highlight

- purple: mark highlight3

  to edit more goto top menu -> settings-> style configurator

here you will find colors for different language

Answer (score 0):

At http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php it's said:

> ***echo*** is not actually a function (it is a language construct)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you have is the default syntax highlighting setting on your notepad++. Its a common feature of IDEs these days. You can check your setting what the highlighting color stands for. It doesn't necessarily indicates an error or warning but merely as a visual aid for the developers/users to see where a tag starts and ends and what syntaxes he/she is using.